# Blazor - issue clearing validation errors when manually setting form data

Tags: validation, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have found many examples here of clearing validation errors in code but
nothing seems to be working for me.  I am using MudBlazor controls although I don't think that matters.  Here is a shortened version of my form:

```html
 <EditForm Model="@Claimant"
              OnValidSubmit="@AddClaim">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
     <MudTextField @bind-Value="@Claimant.AddressLine1" id="AddressLine1"
                                  Label="Address Line 1" Variant="Variant.Outlined"
                                  Margin="Margin.Dense" For="@(() => Claimant.AddressLine1)" MaxLength="100"></MudTextField>
                    <MudTextField @bind-Value="@Claimant.AddressLine2"
                                  Label="Address Line 2" Variant="Variant.Outlined"
                                  Margin="Margin.Dense" For="@(() => Claimant.AddressLine2)" MaxLength="100"></MudTextField>
                <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Disabled=@IsDisabled
                           Style="display: inline-flex; justify-content: space-around; align-items: flex-start;"
                           StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.NoteAdd"
                           Color="Color.Primary"
                           ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit">
                    Submit Claim
                </MudButton>
```

When I click the submit button with no values entered it shows the errors as expected.  I have some code for address validation that the user then selects from and I set some form fields manually:

```csharp
    protected Claimant Claimant { get; set; } = new();
    private EditContext EC { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        EC = new EditContext(Claimant);
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

     protected void SuggestedAddressClick()
    {
        var selectedAddress = SuggestedAddresses[(int)selectedValue];

        if (selectedAddress != null)
        {
            Claimant.AddressLine1 = selectedAddress.Line1;  // The error for the following fields should be cleard after setting.
            Claimant.City = selectedAddress.City;
            Claimant.State = selectedAddress.StateProvince;
            Claimant.ZipCode = selectedAddress.PostalCode;

            EC.Validate();                                    //Does Not Work
            EC.NotifyValidationStateChanged();                //Does Not Work
            EC.NotifyFieldChanged(EC.Field("AddressLine1"));  //Does Not Work
            StateHasChanged();
        }

    }
```

This code sets the values in form as expected and I see the values in the model.  The problem is, none of the lines of code to clear the validation errors work.  The errors only clear if I click the submit button again OR I click into each field and click or tab out.

Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: `<InputText @bind-Value="Address.Line1" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@( () => Address.Line1)" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be creating a new `EditContext` in code - but the way you configured your `EditForm` means that will create its own `EditContext`.

Try passing your `EditContext` to the `EditForm` (instead of the model)

`<EditForm EditContext="@EC" OnValidSubmit="@AddClaim">`

Comment: I did try this but now none of the validation triggers.  It always goes to AddClaim() on a submit

Comment: That seems like a better question to be asking then - how to get DataAnnotationsValidator working with MudBlazor...

Comment: Data annotations do work with MudBlazor as I stated. The form show validation errors as expected.  The issue is this - IF I have a validation error on a field say because it is required, and then I fill the field in code, NOT the UI, I want the validation error to be removed

Comment: I misread your original post.  I copied the original line I had and changed the Model to "@EC" instead of the EditContext property which you correctly pointed out to me.  Once I did that, it works as expected!